# Scroll não funciona no modal!

Tags: css, modal

Ola fiz um modal usando apenas CSS e JavaScript porem na hora que atinge o 100% da tela a barra de rolagem não funciona. Segue meu codigo do meu HTML e CSS

HTML

```
<div class="btnMsg">
  <button class="ripple" v-on:click="teste">Nova Mensagem</button>
</div>

<div id="edit-modal-container">
  <div class="modal-background" id="modalEditMsg">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="select">
          <select v-model="formMsg.codTipo" class="select-text" required>
            <option value="" selected></option>
            <option value="1">Alerta</option>
            <option value="2">Falha</option>
          </select>
          <span class="select-highlight"></span>
          <span class="select-bar"></span>
          <label class="select-label">Tipo</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group field">
        <input v-model="formMsg.titulo" type="text" class="form__field" placeholder="Titulo da Mensagem"
          name="msgTitle" id="msgTitle" maxlength="50" required>
        <label for="msgTitle" class="form__label">Titulo da mensagem</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group field">
        <md-datepicker v-model="formMsg.tempo">
          <label>Data Limite</label>
        </md-datepicker>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group field">
        <input v-model="formMsg.url" type="text" class="form__field" placeholder="Titulo da Mensagem"
          name="msgTitle" id="msgUrl" required>
        <label class="form__label" for="msgUrl">URL</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group field">
        <input class="form__field" type="file" id="uploadArquivo" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, application/pdf"
          @change="()=>{alert('Mudei')}" />
        <label class="form__label" for="uploadArquivo">Arquivo</label>
        <p><small>Extenções aceitas: .jpg, .png. .pdf</small></p>
      </div>

      <div class="form__group field">
        <textarea class="form__field" v-model="formMsg.mensagem" name="mensagem" id="mensagem" maxlength="300"
          rows="2"></textarea>
        <label class="form__label" for="mensagem">Mensagem</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form__group field">
        <div class="switch" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; padding: 10px 30px;">
          <p>Ativo</p>
          <p>Leitura obrigatoria</p>
        </div>

        <div class="switch">
          <div class="switch-button">
            <input class="switch-button-checkbox" checked type="checkbox"></input>
            <label class="switch-button-label" for=""><span class="switch-button-label-span">Não</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="switch-button">
            <input class="switch-button-checkbox" type="checkbox"></input>
            <label class="switch-button-label" for=""><span class="switch-button-label-span">Não</span></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modalFoter">
        <button>Salvar</button>
        <button v-on:click="cancel">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html.modal-active, body.modal-active {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#modal-container, #edit-modal-container {
    position: fixed;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    z-index: 1;
}
#modal-container.four, #edit-modal-container.four{
    z-index: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
}
#modal-container.four .modal-background, #edit-modal-container.four .modal-background {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
#modal-container.four .modal-background .modal, #edit-modal-container.four .modal-background .modal {
    animation: blowUpModal 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four + .content, #edit-modal-container.four + .content{
    z-index: 1;
    animation: blowUpContent 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four.out .modal-background .modal, #edit-modal-container.four.out .modal-background .modal {
    animation: blowUpModalTwo 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
    
}
#modal-container.four.out, #edit-modal-container.four.out {
    animation: blowUpContentTwo 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
.modal-background {
    display: table-cell;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.modal-background .modal {
    background: white;
    padding: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
}
.modal-background .modal h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.modal-background .modal p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.content {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.modalFoter{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: #2d98da;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
}

.modalCab{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.modalCab a{
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modalFoter a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.modalFoter a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2d98da;
}

.modalFoter a.attach{
   margin-left: 20%;
}

div.modal-background div.modal p.dataCad{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function teste() {
      $('#modal-container').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('out');
        $('body').removeAttr('class');
      });
      var modal = $('#modalEditMsg').detach()
      $('#edit-modal-container').append(modal);
      $('#edit-modal-container').removeAttr('class').addClass('four');
      $('body').addClass('modal-active');
}
```

Se puderem ajudar agradeço!

Comment: Oi Leonardo! Você poderia incluir seu HTML também? Dessa forma fica mais fácil reproduzir e encontrar o erro. Valeu!

Comment: Ola, adicionei meu código HTML... Muito Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Em qual parte voce quer o scroll? Se for somente na modal, setando o `overflow` voce consegue atingir o desejado...

```
.modal {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 90vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```js
function teste() {
      $('#modal-container').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('out');
        $('body').removeAttr('class');
      });
      var modal = $('#modalEditMsg').detach()
      $('#edit-modal-container').append(modal);
      $('#edit-modal-container').removeAttr('class').addClass('four');
      $('body').addClass('modal-active');
}

$('#tester').click(function () {
  teste();
});
```

```css
html.modal-active, body.modal-active {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#modal-container, #edit-modal-container {
    position: fixed;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    z-index: 1;
}
#modal-container.four, #edit-modal-container.four{
    z-index: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
}
#modal-container.four .modal-background, #edit-modal-container.four .modal-background {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
#modal-container.four .modal-background .modal, #edit-modal-container.four .modal-background .modal {
    animation: blowUpModal 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four + .content, #edit-modal-container.four + .content{
    z-index: 1;
    animation: blowUpContent 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four.out .modal-background .modal, #edit-modal-container.four.out .modal-background .modal {
    animation: blowUpModalTwo 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
    
}
#modal-container.four.out, #edit-modal-container.four.out {
    animation: blowUpContentTwo 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
.modal-background {
    display: table-cell;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.modal-background .modal {
    background: white;
    padding: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
}
.modal-background .modal h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.modal-background .modal p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.content {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.modalFoter{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: #2d98da;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
}

.modalCab{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.modalCab a{
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modalFoter a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.modalFoter a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2d98da;
}

.modalFoter a.attach{
   margin-left: 20%;
}

div.modal-background div.modal p.dataCad{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.modal {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 90vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btnMsg">
  <button id="tester" class="ripple" v-on:click="teste">Nova Mensagem</button>
</div>

<div id="edit-modal-container">
  <div class="modal-background" id="modalEditMsg">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="select">
          <select v-model="formMsg.codTipo" class="select-text" required>
            <option value="" selected></option>
            <option value="1">Alerta</option>
            <option value="2">Falha</option>
          </select>
          <span class="select-highlight"></span>
          <span class="select-bar"></span>
          <label class="select-label">Tipo</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group field">
        <input v-model="formMsg.titulo" type="text" class="form__field" placeholder="Titulo da Mensagem"
          name="msgTitle" id="msgTitle" maxlength="50" required>
        <label for="msgTitle" class="form__label">Titulo da mensagem</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group field">
        <md-datepicker v-model="formMsg.tempo">
          <label>Data Limite</label>
        </md-datepicker>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group field">
        <input v-model="formMsg.url" type="text" class="form__field" placeholder="Titulo da Mensagem"
          name="msgTitle" id="msgUrl" required>
        <label class="form__label" for="msgUrl">URL</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group field">
        <input class="form__field" type="file" id="uploadArquivo" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, application/pdf"
          @change="()=>{alert('Mudei')}" />
        <label class="form__label" for="uploadArquivo">Arquivo</label>
        <p><small>Extenções aceitas: .jpg, .png. .pdf</small></p>
      </div>

      <div class="form__group field">
        <textarea class="form__field" v-model="formMsg.mensagem" name="mensagem" id="mensagem" maxlength="300"
          rows="2"></textarea>
        <label class="form__label" for="mensagem">Mensagem</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form__group field">
        <div class="switch" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; padding: 10px 30px;">
          <p>Ativo</p>
          <p>Leitura obrigatoria</p>
        </div>

        <div class="switch">
          <div class="switch-button">
            <input class="switch-button-checkbox" checked type="checkbox"></input>
            <label class="switch-button-label" for=""><span class="switch-button-label-span">Não</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="switch-button">
            <input class="switch-button-checkbox" type="checkbox"></input>
            <label class="switch-button-label" for=""><span class="switch-button-label-span">Não</span></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modalFoter">
        <button>Salvar</button>
        <button v-on:click="cancel">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo. Muito Obrigado!